# SOLR indexing and searching?

Tags: indexing, solr

Currently, I'm trying to add a new field to our SOLR engine.

I've added the following into the schema.xml file.

```
<field name='FIELDNAME'      type='string'  indexed='true' stored='false' />
```

The xml passed to solr for indexing is:

```
<FIELDNAMES>
     <FIELDNAME>1</FIELDNAME>
                :
                :
                :
     <FIELDNAME>N</FIELDNAME>
</FIELDNAMES>
```

For some reason when I do a solr query via the admin or anywhere else with `FIELDNAME:1` nothing is returned.

What would be a recommend way to go forward with solving this problem?

Comment: is `<FIELDNAMES>...</FIELDNAMES>` the real content of the FIELDNAME field?

Comment: No...it's <fieldname>1</fieldname><fieldname>2</fieldname> going to <fieldname>N</fieldname> where N is the Nth value.

Answer (score 2):

The xml format that Solr expects is [described in the wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateXmlMessages#add.2BAC8-update). Basically, you have a "add" tag containing one or more "doc" tags for each of your document. Each "doc" is made of several "field" tags.

Do a Solr query with q=*:* to see if you manage to index at least one document.

Answer (score 0):

I found my problem. The field wasn't added to the Solr Doc file that's ingested into solr.